# Python Error: ImportError: No module named FFT

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python version 2.7.3 in windows and ubuntu as well as 2.6 in windows. Why does the following code that imports several modules result in an error in both windows as well as ubuntu?

```
from FFT import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from sampling import *
import pickle
import scipy
```

> ImportError: No module named FFT

Comment: What is FFT ? Where are you running the import from ?

Comment: Where are your expecting `FFT` to come from? It is part of `numpy` so does `from numpy import fft` work?

Comment: Only `pickle` is in the Python standard library. The other imports refer to packages you must install separately.

Comment: Please provide more details on the modules you are trying to import and where they are located relative to your script

Comment: Quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask "If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer." As others mentiooned, FFT is not a standard python module. You need to install it (if it exists). However you might be trying to use numpy fft, in which case you need to use from numpy import fft

Comment: @Berriot FFT means fast fourier transform, and finally it worked with new version of portable python

Answer (score 4):

```
from FFT import *
```

I believe this `^^^` is meant to be:

```
from numpy.fft import *
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `fftpack` instead `fft`

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
```

see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to shift to portable python 
http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.6.1/